# Embedding Wistia video in a Mobile App developed using Titanium

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-mobile, wistia

We are developing a Mobile App using the Titanium framework, we need to embed some videos in one of the screens. Appcelerator API documentation that I am following is [located here](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Media.VideoPlayer). My code looks as follows, currently it shows a blank screen :

```
var welcomeWin = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    title:'Welcome Video',
    backgroundColor:'#fff' 
});


var videoplayer = Titanium.Media.createVideoPlayer({
    top:2,
    autoplay:true,
    height:300,
    width:300,
    url:'https://fast.wistia.net/embed/iframe/thewistiaurl',
    mediaControlStyle:Titanium.Media.VIDEO_CONTROL_DEFAULT,
    scalingMode:Titanium.Media.VIDEO_SCALING_ASPECT_FIT
});


welcomeWin.add(videoplayer);
```

Comment: is the URL an actual link to the video file, or an html page? Because it needs to be a direct link to the video itself

Comment: Its the same url that I am using for embedding the video inside an iFrame of an HTML page.

Comment: thats not an answer to my question :) Sounds like it is an html page, but you'd need to check!

Comment: As an example : this is the exact url that I am using https://fast.wistia.net/embed/iframe/vejo0vd0oa

Comment: After checking Wistia API docs, It turns out that the direct URLs look like this: http://embed.wistia.com/deliveries/02b2a615c6cd0db58132d2cb92fda84e04c9d8f3.bin . I am now trying to find how to obtain the direct urls for my videos. Thanks!

Comment: If you do not find a proper way to load video from your urls, then you may try WebView as well as I believe it should work for any URLs which indirectly load videos